# Extract year from different date strings in alist

Tags: string, time-date

I have a function that tries to extract the year from date strings stored in an alist below:

```elisp
(setq entry
 '(("date" . "1998/03")
   ("origdate" . "1930")))

(defun extract-year (date)
  (let ((string (cdr (assoc (symbol-name 'date) entry))))
  (progn
    (string-match
     "\\([0-9]\\{4\\}\\)[/-年\\.]?\\([0-9]+\\)?[/-月\\.]?\\([0-9]+\\)?[/-日\\.]?"
     string)
    (match-string 1 string))))
```

I would like to call, for example, `(extract-year date)` to get `"1998"` and `(extract-year origdate)` to get `"1930"`.

Comment: You should simply pass the string, e.g., `(extract-year "date")`.

Comment: So `(assoc (symbol-name 'date) entry)` should simply be `(assoc date entry)`?

Comment: Yes. Your function is not clean to me. A function's return value should be decided only by its arguments whenever it's possible. And a function's purpose should be as simple as possible.

Comment: Other than what I pointed out above, can you show me how to make the function more concise?

Comment: I don't not know the purpose. If you want to extract year from something like 2020/11/09, you can create `(defun extract-year (date-string) ...)` which can be used as `(extract-year "2020/11/09") => 2020`

Comment: Could you please change the question title to clarify what you're asking? The title now doesn't seem to correspond to what you're asking (nor does it make sense, to me). Thx.

Comment: Is there a ready-made function to parse a general date-string into its components?